# return item datas in a view from invoice

Tags: laravel

i've used the following models: invoice, invoice_product and the pro_stock as listed bellow

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(invoice_product::class);
    }
```

which return the invoice products, then

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsTo(prodStock::class);
   }
```

which gets the ids from stock table and the invoice controller

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $items = invoice_product::find($id);
        $invoice = invoice::with(['items.products'])
        ->findOrFail($id);
        return view('pages.InvoiceDetails', compact('invoice'));
    }
```

in my view blade i return

```
 @foreach($invoice->items as $item)
                        <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                            <td class="table-name">{{$item->products->pro_name}}</td>
                            <td class="table-price">{{$item->unit_price}}</td>
                            <td class="table-qty">{{$item->qty}}</td>
                            <td class="table-total text-right">{{$item->total}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

and its ruturns

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View:
```

Once ive tested  using print_r($invoice->toArray())
returned me these data, i want to replaced pro_stock_id with its name

```
[items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 130 [invoice_id] => 87 [pro_stock_id] => 7 [unit_price] => 200 [qty] => 1 [total] => 200 [created_at] => 2019-11-27 09:32:20 [updated_at] => 2019-11-27 09:32:20 [products] => ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 131 [invoice_id] => 87 [pro_stock_id] => 8 [unit_price] => 300 [qty] => 12 [total] => 3600 [created_at] => 2019-11-27 09:32:20 [updated_at] => 2019-11-27 09:32:20 [products] => ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 132 [invoice_id] => 87 [pro_stock_id] => 4 [unit_price] => 300 [qty] => 1 [total] => 300 [created_at] => 2019-11-27 09:32:20 [updated_at] => 2019-11-27 09:32:20 [products] => ) ) )
```

Comment: @foreach($invoice->items as $item)

Comment: please print_r($invoice->toArray()); and put array in this question.